# Java - Different paint with multiple threads that have thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint, thread-sleep

I'm newbie and I'm trying to make a game but than I don't understand how to use repaint() from different paint with different threads too. One thread with thread.sleep and the other one doesn't have.

Here's my piece of code :

GamePanel :

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

EnemyEngine enemyE = new EnemyEngine();

public GamePanel() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){            
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){            
                enemyE.update();
                enemyE.repaint();

                try { 
                    Thread.sleep(1000/10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // board painting
}

}
```

EnemyEngine:

```
public class EnemyEngine extends JPanel{

Vector<Enemy> enemyVect = new Vector<>();

Random rand = new Random();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    for (Enemy enemy : enemyVect) {
        enemy.render(g);
    }
}

public void update() { 
    for (Enemy enemy : enemyVect) {
        enemy.move();
    }
}

}
```

I have already search on the internet but it still didn't work...or maybe I'm the stupid one :/

Please help me senpai

Comment: First, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/. Second, `while (true) repaint();` will choke the Swing event thread; you don’t need to paint hundreds of times per second. Only call repaint() when the data that determines what gets painted has changed. Third, you must use javax.swing.Timer or java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(…) to make sure you only call Swing methods from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: In general, it is also advisable to delegate "painting" and other such user-interface tasks to one thread ... perhaps, a thread that does nothing else.  This thread might sleep waiting for an asynchronous signal that tells it, "please now go and update the user interface," whereupon it wakes up and does so.  (This design also avoids overwhelming the GUI with requests.)

Comment: I have tried to use timer but I don't understand how to use it with graphics

Comment: You don’t use Graphics with a Timer.  A Timer’s ActionListener should call `repaint()`, which causes Swing to automatically invoke paintComponent (and some other painting methods).

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand clearly your issue about repaint?
If you want to refresh ui immediately, why don't you use paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment above.